# Is it possible to make GTM Custom HTML tag not to insert new <script/> tags into the DOM?

Tags: google-tag-manager, facebook-pixel

There is a Single Page App with Facebook Pixel integrated via Google Tag Manager as Custom HTML tag.

```
<script>
  (function() {
    fbq({{Facebook Pixel Track Type}}, {{Facebook Pixel Event Name}});
  })()
</script>
```

This tag is firing on every history change. And on every history change new

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="">fbq(google_tag_manager["GTM-XXXXXXX"].macro('gtm22'),google_tag_manager["GTM-XXXXXXX"].macro('gtm23'));</script>
```

is inserted into the DOM.

[multiple script tags added to the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZlAN.png)

The only way I found just remove executed script tags.

```
<script id='facebook-pixel-hit'>
  (function() {
    fbq({{Facebook Pixel Track Type}}, {{Facebook Pixel Event Name}});
    setTimeout(function() {
      var scriptTag = document.getElementById('facebook-pixel-hit')
      if (scriptTag)
        scriptTag.remove()
    }, 500);
  })()
</script>
```

but it doesn't look like a good solution.

Are there any ways to avoid adding multiple  tags into the DOM?

Comment: Do you really need to fire that tag on every history change?

Comment: There are other tags in app, which are fired similarly. This is like example.